# In java, how do I sort a generic class T on a Field variable sent to me

Tags: java, sorting, generics, field

```
// this function can be called if the objects sent is Comparable (they have
// already chosen the field and how it compares)
public void mySort(Object [] obj) {
     Arrays.sort(obj, null);     // this sorts based on compareTo() 
                                 // method of comparable object
}
```

My question is how would the following function need to be changed to sort the array by the Field field. I have tried many different ways of implementing it and just put code below which represents what I was trying to do.

```
// this function should be used to sort a generic array of T objects, to be
// compared on the Field field
public static <T> void mySort2(T [] obj, Field field) {
    Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<T>(){
          public int compare(T obj1, T obj2)
          {
             return obj1.field.compareTo(obj2.field); // this does not work
                             //  since I need to the name of the field and
                             //  not a variable, however I do not know what
                             //  T will be when it is sent to me
          }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`Field::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) to reflectively access the field. After that, you will need to cast to `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks! After some trial and error, I think I got it to work as I asked in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to pass a `Field` instance and look up the field reflectively? As a possible alternative (which may be more performant, depending on your JVM implementation), you can pass a lambda or method reference for accessing the field:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void mySort(
    T[] array,
    Function<T, U> func) {
  Arrays.sort(array, (a, b) -> func.apply(a).compareTo(func.apply(b));
}
```

Which you would call like:

```
Foo[] foos = ...
mySort(foos, Foo::getMyField);
```

If you're stuck with Java 7, you can do the same thing but it's a bit more verbose:

```
public interface Function<I, O> {
  O apply(I input);
}

public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void mySort(
    T[] array,
    final Function<T, U> func) {
  Arrays.sort(array,
      new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override public int compareTo(T a, T b) {
          return func.apply(a).compareTo(func.apply(b));
        }
      });
}
```

Which you would call like:

```
Foo[] foos = ...
mySort(foos,
    new Function<Foo, Integer>() {
      @Override public Integer apply(Foo foo) {
        return foo.getMyField();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! As long as I do not need to look up Fields reflectively, I will definitely look to use this type of setup. Unfortunately, I am not sure if this is a hard requirement or not at this time (waiting on others).

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to do it with `Field`, and an answer was given. If this is a strict requirement for whatever reason then my answer is moot, but if it is not it is a nicer way to do it without reflection.

First, a quick mention, instead of `T[] obj`, it will need to be `List<T> obj`.

Now for the rest of the changes,

1. The method's type-parameter was `<T>`, I have changed it to `<T, F extends Comparable<F>>`. `F` stands for "field". `F` needs to be comparable to itself which is why it needs to be `Comparable<F>`.
2. You need a way to get the `F` from the `T`. So you give a `Function<T, F>` which I will give an example of below.
3. The compare method needs to return `getter.apply(obj1).compareTo(getter.apply(obj2))`.

Here is your finished product

```
public static <T, F extends Comparable<F>> void mySort2(List<T> obj, final Function<T, F> getter) {
    Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T obj1, T obj2) {
            return getter.apply(obj1).compareTo(getter.apply(obj2));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is an example of calling it to sort strings by length.

```
List<String> list = getSomeListOfStringsSomehow();
mySort2(list, (String s) -> g.length());
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also an interesting solution that I will consider if using Fields is not a strict requirement.